# Excel Dropdown to Filter Pivot Tables on Separate Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've created a drop down using Form Control Combo Box for the user to select/filter the data without having to go to the pivot table itself. How can I connect the Form Control Combo Box through VBA to a pivot table in another sheet so the value selected from the drop down is the filter to be used in the pivot table in the separate worksheet?

I've tried the code below but the pivot table still doesn't catch the text in the drop down. The filter in the pivot table still does not change when I select a different item from the drop down.

```
Sub Macro34()

 Dim valmonth As String
 valmonth = Range("D3").Value

Sheets("Pivot_Main").PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = _
        valmonth

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to post more code for an Minimal Reproduceable Example Eg:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Somebody may be able to just see your error, but without the ability to test any solutions I come up with I won't even bother looking into it.